# RichTextBox1 Active then RichTextBox2 is Inactive

Tags: vb.net, vb.net-2010

Could you help me in setting focus to RichTextBox? I am trying to create a multiple RichTextBox. When I OpenFile Text files All RichTextBox1, RichTextBox2 and RichTextBox3 was use.

I am hoping when RichTextBox1 is Active then the other RichTextBox Inactive and not use

I am trying to set then in focus, but I don't know how to use it.

```
Private Sub OpenToolStripMenuItem_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles OpenToolStripMenuItem.Click
    Try
        With OpenFileDialog1
            .Filter = "Text files(*.txt)|*.txt|" & "All files|*.*"
            If Not focussedrtb Is Nothing Then
                focussedrtb = rtb1
                .ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK
                filename = .FileName
                sr = New StreamReader(.OpenFile)
                rtb1.Text = sr.ReadToEnd()
                rtb1.Focus()
                rtb1.Enabled = True
                rtb2.Enabled = False
            Else
                rtb2.Text = sr.ReadToEnd()
                rtb1.Enabled = False
                rtb2.Enabled = True
            End If
        End With
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    Finally
        If Not (sr Is Nothing) Then
            sr.Close()
        End If
    End Try
End Sub
```

Thanks for editing my question.

Answer (score 0):

If you trying to set focus to `rtb1` then reorder those:

```
rtb1.Enabled = True
rtb2.Enabled = False
rtb1.Focus()
```

or actually one of these

```
me.ActiveControl = rtb1
```

or

`rtb1.Select(`)

**

**Update:**

**

```
    If Not focussedrtb Is Nothing Then
        focussedrtb = rtb1
        .ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK
        filename = .FileName
        sr = New StreamReader(.OpenFile)
        rtb1.Text = sr.ReadToEnd()
        rtb1.Enabled = True
        rtb2.Enabled = False
        rtb1.Focus()
    Else
        rtb1.Enabled = False
        rtb2.Enabled = True
        rtb2.Text = sr.ReadToEnd()
    End If
```

To explain you need to enable before you can put value to a textbox

Comment: i just want to ask if i going to use Else statement?

if you don't mind could you edit my code?

i try to use your answer

rtb1.Enabled = True
rtb2.Enabled = False
rtb1.Focus()

or actually one of these

me.ActiveControl = rtb1

or

rtb1.Select() but it didn't work

Comment: rtb1 is only functioning.

when i openFile in rtb1 it works

but when i openfile in rtb2 it didn't work

Comment: should i create a new try and catch?

Comment: what do you mean try to update? sorry I am not good in programming because im just a newbie.

Comment: See code changed in update I created: Your order was incorrect. For example you need to turn on car first (enabled = true) before you can drive it(rtb2.Text = sr.ReadToEnd()) or do anything with it.

Comment: sorry i didn't notice your update above.

I try to put your update code to my code. but the .showdialog() = DialogResult.OK  there is an error

Comment: .ShowDialog() "Expression is a value and therefore cannot be target of an assignment"

thats the error shows

Comment: `If Not focussedrtb Is Nothing And .ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK Then
                    focussedrtb = rtb1
                    filename = .FileName
                    sr = New StreamReader(.OpenFile)
                    rtb1.Text = sr.ReadToEnd()
                    rtb1.Enabled = True
                    rtb2.Enabled = False
                    rtb1.Focus()
                Else
                    focussedrtb = rtb2
                    rtb1.Enabled = False
                    rtb2.Enabled = True
                    rtb2.Text = sr.ReadToEnd()
                End If`

Comment: Thanks for the help. i can't vote your answer because I'm a new user in stackoverflow so that i didn't earned reputation.

i really appreciate your help.

Thanks a lot.

ididn't get the right answers to my problem. but thanks for giving me a ideas :)